# How to refer to implementor class with @ClosureParams from trait

Tags: groovy

I would like to use `@ClosureParams` with a method in a trait, that takes a Closure as input, which will be passed the trait's implementer when called.

Consider the following example:

```
trait Fooable {
    void foo(@ClosureParams(????) Closure callable) {
        callable.call(this)
    }
}

class Bar implements Fooable {
    String baz
}

new Bar().foo { it.baz == "foo'ed" }
```

How do I tell the static analyser that the `it` passed to the closure is actually `Bar` (last line). What should value should I pass to @ClosureParams in the definition of the `foo` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work with traits at the moment (Groovy **2.4.13**), because there is no [`ClosureSignatureHint`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.13/html/gapi/groovy/transform/stc/ClosureSignatureHint.html) implementation that allows you to define at a runtime type of a hint that uses class type that implements method from trait interface. If your trait was implemented only by `Bar` class then you could specify closure parameter type as:

```
@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
trait Fooable {
    void foo(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType, options = ["Bar"]) Closure callable) {
        callable.call(this)
    }
}
```

But it's not the case.

`@ClosureParams` won't even recognize generic type if used with trait. Let's consider following definition:

```
@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
trait Fooable<T> {
    void foo(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType, options = ["T"]) Closure callable) {
        callable.call(this)
    }
}
```

We could expect that `Bar` class that implements `Fooable<Bar>` should work like a charm, but it does not unfortunately:

[image]

Closure parameter in this case is recognized as `T` type. It happens because method `foo` is implemented inside `Bar` class and `@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class,options = {"T"})` is also compiled at `Bar` class level, so it is not aware of generic type `T`. Let's take a look at compiled `Bar` class to understand what's going on:

```
public class Bar implements Fooable<Bar>, GroovyObject {
    private String baz;

    public Bar() {
        String var1 = "test";
        this.baz = var1;
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
        Helper.$init$(this);
        Object var10000 = null;
    }

    @TraitBridge(
        traitClass = Fooable.class,
        desc = "(Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)V"
    )
    public void foo(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class,options = {"T"}) Closure arg1) {
        Helper.foo(this, arg1);
        Object var10000 = null;
    }

    // some other methods
}
```

This is what you will see if you open `Bar.class` as a decompiled file.

Generics will work fine if instead of trait we would use abstract class. In this case abstract generic class `Fooable<T>` would implement `foo` method so `Bar` class would refer to implementation from `Fooable<T>` class - a class that is aware of `T` type. In this case IDE would resolve `T` correctly and suggest `Bar` instead.

So what are the options when using trait in this case? You could try implementing your own `ClosureSignatureHint` class, but this is not that easy. I did a small experiment - I have defined `NewSimpleType` class and I have copied 1:1 sources from `SimpleType` class. Then I used it as:

```
@CompileStatic
@TypeChecked
trait Fooable {
    void foo(@ClosureParams(value = NewSimpleType, options = ["Bar"]) Closure callable) {
        callable.call(this)
    }
}
```

As you can see I've only replaced Groovy's `SimpleType` with my custom `NewSimpleType`. It didn't work. My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.3) didn't resolve any type. I've even move this class to a separate Maven project and I've build it and added as a dependency - didn't work as well.

I assume it should be possible to implement a hint class that takes caller class type into account. There are some implementations that take closure parameter type from first, second or third parameter. It sounds doable, at least in theory.

Last option that requires least effort is just provide closure parameter type explicitly, e.g.

```
Bar bar = new Bar()
bar.foo { Bar b -> b.baz }
```

It supports all code completion features. The downside is that you can specify different type, like:

```
Bar bar = new Bar()
bar.foo { String b -> b.toLowerCase() }
```

IDE won't complain about that, but it will fail while compiling.

#### Custom `StringParameterHint` use case

I have created for experiments a static closure signature hint that accepts only `java.lang.String` as a parameter:

```
public class StringParameterHint extends ClosureSignatureHint {
    @Override
    public List<ClassNode[]> getClosureSignatures(MethodNode node, SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilationUnit compilationUnit, String[] options, ASTNode usage) {
        final List<ClassNode[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(GenericsUtils.parseClassNodesFromString("java.lang.String", sourceUnit, compilationUnit, node, usage));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then I've set it up with `@ClosureParams` in `Fooable.foo(Closure cl)` method. Unfortunately IDE does not read this hint and does not recognize `it` as a type of `String`:

[image]

But compiler (in IDE) is aware of this closure parameter hint and if I cast parameter to `Bar` like:

```
bar.foo { Bar b -> b.baz }
```

then IDE does not mark it as an incorrect expression, yet compilation fails and program does not start:

```
Error:(11, 19) Groovyc: Expected parameter of type java.lang.String but got tld.company.Bar
Error:(11, 28) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - No such property: baz for class: java.lang.String
```

So it looks like we can force compiler to be closure parameter aware, but this information is not being read by IDE (IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.3 in my case). I guess this might be an IDE issue. I've even moved this `StringParameterHint` class to `groovy.transform.stc` package (I was assuming that maybe IDE loads all hints from this package automatically), but it didn't help.

Comment: Great answer. I am wondering if another approach would be a to use a global AST transformation to detect the use of the `Fooable` trait on a class, and modify/add the `foo` method to the class directly, with the right `@SourceParams` annotation. Will IDE's be able to use the `@SourceParams` in that case, or will it be hidden since its only visible after compilation? 

And no, it will not only be Bar that implements Fooable, many other POGOs will.

Comment: @EgilHansen I'm afraid it may not work either, but it's definitely worth trying. I was able to use custom `StringParameterHint` class that accepts only `String` as a closure parameter - it worked well with compiler, but IDE was completely not aware of this parameter type constraint. I've updated my answer with more details about this use case.